# Is is possible to disable Certificate Transparency (audit log checking) of certificates in Chrome?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, google-chrome

We utilize HTTPS deep packet inspection in our firewall via a trusted root certificate in the Windows certificate store.  Chrome recently pushed forward with a feature to perform additional checks on certificate issuance called Certificate Transparency, where each certificate used (that was issued after a certain date) is checked against a known good list of CAs.

The use of HTTPS deep packet inspection (aka HTTPS proxying/offloading/MiTM) now causes Chrome to error as per [this example](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/52838/3611).

Is it possible to disable the sole feature of audit log checking in Chrome?

**Update in response to [womble's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/704042/88350).**

***This update is wrong.  Womble's answer is correct, see below.***

This is what I originally thought, but it clearly isn't.

Here are screenshots of overly righteous Chrome:

No MiTM:

[image: no mitm]

MiTM:

[image: mitm]

It does appear that it is directly related to cert transparency/audit log checking and not the use of SHA-1 and [upcoming depreciation in nanny Chrome](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/09/09/sha1-deprecation-what-you-need-to-know).  Worth noting that our internal CA cert does expire after 2017.

**Update 2, womble is right:**

Thanks to womble's answer, I re-reviewed [the notice from the Chrome team](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html), and noticed any site with a cert with an expiration 2017+ that uses SHA-1 will get the "affirmatively insecure" warning (the crossed out red lock icon).

To prove my MiTM/proxy the culprit, I used [a salesforce test site](https://sha2test.salesforce.com/s/) (located via ducking [a KB article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=HTTPS-Security-Certificate-Switch-from-SHA-1-to-SHA-256-hash-algorithms&language=en_US))

No MiTM:

[image]

MiTM:

[image]

```
 *note that even with no MiTM Chrome detects this site as "secure, but with minor errors" (that yellow icon) because the cert expires within the 2016 calendar year, not 2017+.
```

My proxy/MiTM is downgrading the algo from SHA-256 to SHA-1.  Tsk Tsk!
Chrome is acting exactly as intended according to the notice, and I do not believe my user's will receive "affirmatively insecure" notifications once I resolve this issue with the MiTM/proxy.

Thanks!

**Update 3:**
Remember to check firmware updates/release notes... SHA-256 now supported.  Update slated Friday.  Should be a-okay.

Comment: I don't _think_ you can disable it, but [you _can_ specify a custom log key with the --certificate-transparency-log flag](https://code.google.com/p/certificate-transparency/wiki/CertTransparencyInChrome#Supplying_your_own_log_key). --ignore-certificate-errors is **not** an option because it will disable any security checks for certificates, not just CT.

Comment: You are correct here as well.  This is what I was reading, but it said nothing about creating the `affirmatively insecure` notice.  I'll have to check if it would produce the `secure, but with minor errors` notice.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the example you're pointing to is actually the one about "The site is using outdated security settings", and not "does not have public audit records", about 99.99% sure that your problem isn't CT, for several reasons:

- It is my understanding that only CA certificates in the system trust store are subject to CT validation; locally-managed CA certificates don't require CT treatment (for pretty much exactly the reason you've got).
- Failing CT validation only matters for EV certificates at the present time, and the only negative impact is that the certificate loses the EV "green bar" treatment.

The error about "using outdated security settings" actually means that your MitM proxy is issuing SHA-1-based certificates with expiry dates in the far future, which probably isn't such a winning idea.

Comment: This is originally what I thought, but as this post is in complement and not answered by the linked to thread, it is not the cause.  I've updated the original question, providing screenshots.  It's a UX thing I'm focused on... it's tough to explain to our legal team the intricacies of encryption use in Chrome when the GC gets this error on their Belkin GPS site (just a minor example).  Granted firefox has it's own cert store, this type of problem is avoided by adding the CA to the trusted CA store.  Chrome relies on Windows cert store... apparently barely.

Comment: womble: please edit your answer so that I can re-upvote you.  My mistake, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: This reminds me of [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52834/what-exactly-does-it-mean-when-chrome-reports-a-certificate-does-not-have-publi/52838#52838)… The Chrome message is probably a bit too confusing!